# How to cancel scheduled Timer Task and run it again?

Tags: java

First of all this is a Minecraft Forge mod but i am sure that you don't need to know forge to solve my issue.

I simply use Keybind "K" to schedule 3 different timers and after that i click "L" to cancel them running again. There is no problem until i start "K" (again) to start my timers again but i get

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled." error in logs.

The code that i use to manage timers:

```
public class KeyBind {
public static Boolean Status = false;
Timer timer = new Timer();



@SubscribeEvent
public void onKeyPressed(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    if (ForgeMain.keybinding.isKeyDown()) {
        if(Status == false) {
            EntityPlayerSP entityPlayerSP = (Minecraft.getMinecraft()).thePlayer;
            entityPlayerSP.addChatComponentMessage((IChatComponent) new ChatComponentText(EnumChatFormatting.YELLOW + "You have successfully ran the NetherWart Macro!"));
            Status = true;
            timer.schedule(new Left(), 100, 38000);
            timer.schedule(new Forward(), 33100, 38000);
            timer.schedule(new Right(), 35100, 38000);
        }
    }if(ForgeMain.keybinding1.isKeyDown()){
        if(Status == true) {
            Status = false;
            System.out.println(Status.booleanValue());
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }

        }
    }
```

And here is one of my timers (They all work the same way differences are the direction to move and  moving time):

```
public class Right extends TimerTask {
@Override
public void run() {
    int left = Minecraft.getMinecraft().gameSettings.keyBindRight.getKeyCode();

    long oldTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - oldTime < 33000) {
        KeyBinding.setKeyBindState(left, true);
    }
    KeyBinding.setKeyBindState(left, false);

}
```

}

Edit:

Okey i learnt that i have to create another timer now i use:

```
    @SubscribeEvent
public void onKeyPressed(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
    if (ForgeMain.keybinding.isKeyDown()) {
        if(Status == false) {
            EntityPlayerSP entityPlayerSP = (Minecraft.getMinecraft()).thePlayer;
            entityPlayerSP.addChatComponentMessage((IChatComponent) new ChatComponentText(EnumChatFormatting.YELLOW + "You have successfully ran the NetherWart Macro!"));
            Status = true;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new Left(), 100, 38000);
            timer.schedule(new Forward(), 33100, 38000);
            timer.schedule(new Right(), 35100, 38000);
        }
    }if(ForgeMain.keybinding1.isKeyDown()){
        if(Status == true) {    
            Status = false;
            System.out.println(Status.booleanValue());
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }

        }
    }
```

}

But now i do not know how to cancel the timer (in code timer.cancel(); ofc does not work.)

Comment: According to the doc: cancel() Cancels the TimerTask and removes it from the Timer's queue. As it's removed from the Timer's queue you would have to make a new one.

Comment: This is `java.util.Timer`? I ask, as API docs suggest that repeated calls to `cancel` and `purge` should not be a problem. If it is that class, I'd be inclined to create the `Timer` as well as schedule it

Comment: oh, i understand you eeedev. But if i create new timer by clicking "k" (with Timer timer = new Timer();) i wont be able to cancel it by pressing "L". Do you have a solution for this ?

Comment: Don't move the declaration of the `Timer`. Iniialise it to null where it *was* and create it in your `status == false` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timer.cancel()` terminates the Timer, so it can no longer be used to schedule new tasks. You will need to instantiate a new timer after you cancel the Timer.

```
public class KeyBind {
    public static Boolean Status = false;
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onKeyPressed(InputEvent.KeyInputEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
        if (ForgeMain.keybinding.isKeyDown()) {
            if(Status == false) {
                EntityPlayerSP entityPlayerSP = (Minecraft.getMinecraft()).thePlayer;
                entityPlayerSP.addChatComponentMessage((IChatComponent) new ChatComponentText(EnumChatFormatting.YELLOW + "You have successfully ran the NetherWart Macro!"));
                Status = true;
                timer.schedule(new Left(), 100, 38000);
                timer.schedule(new Forward(), 33100, 38000);
                timer.schedule(new Right(), 35100, 38000);
            }
        }if(ForgeMain.keybinding1.isKeyDown()){
            if(Status == true) {
                Status = false;
                System.out.println(Status.booleanValue());
                timer.cancel();
                timer = new Timer();
            }

        }
    }
}
```